# Unable to register Gears of War 5 in Logitech G Hub

Tags: technical-issues, mouse, gears-5

Logitech G Hub automatically detects games and changes my mouse settings depending on where I'm focused. However, Gears of War 5 is not listed my list of games.

After some digging I came to discover that Gears 5 is installed through the Microsoft Store. The `Gears5.exe` is in fact under the `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\*` folder, which even my admin account doesn't have access to...

I was able to give my local user `Full Control` of the `WindowsApps` folder, however, the it threw an error when trying to modify certain files underneath that directory (including the `Gears5.exe` file).

Is there any way to fix this? I know this is an anti-hack measure, but I just want my damn DPI settings to be controllable through G Hub. It irks me that I don't get full control of my own machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

G hub adds new games every month. I am guessing Gears of 5 wasn't added yet or will not be until future updates. To add it in manually, you have to go to the games and applications screen(the screen you are on in the screenshot) and press "add game". It is on the far right, so you may have to press the arrow to scroll to the right. Press add game and browse for the .exe file for gears of war 5. It will get added and you can customize it.

Comment: The problem is that the `.exe` is in a special Windows folder that you can't really take control of. LGHUB would get permission denied because it's in the special folder. I've also tried messing around with changing the permissions but it won't let you become the owner of the .exe files

Comment: @KolobCanyon Any update? Same issue, when trying to add an exe from local path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE

Comment: @RazvanR I never figured out how to do this and just gave up.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me (to get Logitech G Hub to access the WindowsApps folder): https://forums.forzamotorsport.net/turn10_postsm780252_How-to-find-the-game--exe-shortcut-to-write-in-Logitech-Gaming-Software.aspx#post_780252

Run PowerShell as administrator then run:

```
cd "C:\Program Files"
takeown /F WindowsApps
icacls WindowsApps /grant Administrators:F
icacls WindowsApps /grant Administrators:F /Τ
icacls WindowsApps /setowner "NT Service\TrustedInstaller"
```

Edit: I wasn't specifically targeting the Gears of War .exe, just another .exe within the WindowsApps folder